# conversion of $\cos \theta$ = 0.248 without a calculator

Tags: calculus

$$\cos \theta =  0.248$$

is there a way to mechanically do this without having to draw curves?  I want to find $\theta$ in degrees

I asked my calc 2 teacher about this and he said I must use a calculator. I know how to do the simple $1/2$, $\sqrt{3}/2$ etc. because it is on the unit circle

however i'm taking calc 3 now and one of the questions (from several) in the text boils down to this answer - the quiz had the same format but we are not allowed calculators so i was kind of stuck (technically it was an online quiz so we were, but for the exams we are not and I'm afraid questions like this may show up on the exam)

I do know it is $\theta= \cos^{-1} 0.248...$ from here I am stuck

Comment: There is no such theta. $-1 \leq \cos \theta \leq 1$

Comment: okay how about cos 0 = .248 .. I was just using a random number but this is what the question boils down to. The answer was 73.4 degrees but I have no idea how to get that

Comment: One methodology is to use the Taylor Series for arccos, as described here: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=taylor+series+arccos&lk=3

Comment: I don't believe there is any particularly good way. For an approximation, it might be worth remembering a few terms in that Taylor Series linked above. However, I'm fairly confident they won't ask you to invert angles like that in an exam which does not allow calculators. The person you should be talking to about this is your lecturer - in general, they're happy to be emailed about such queries.

Comment: If the text is asking you to evaluate arccosines by hand, they're probably giving you inputs for which you can derive the result through trig identities and the standard 30-45-60 angles. If it's not possible to perform such a derivation, you're probably not actually supposed to evaluate it.

Comment: ya its not standard angles - i agree with her not asking on the exam but one never knows I should email her - I didn't even think about taylor approximations I could probably get it close enough with a 4th or 5th approximation. Okay thanks for the help guys, sorry for such a simple question

Comment: Please change the question's title. It is blatantly incorrect.

Comment: It's impossible that $\cos\theta$ to be greater than 1. I don't understand that why this question have not been deleted yet.

Comment: $\large\theta \in {\mathbb C}$.

Comment: @Integrator It was just to maintain the quality of question. I hope you won't mind that.

Comment: You might be forgetting that external users also browse this site and search for the questions. It really doesn't matter how old the question is, people will still find it.

Comment: @Integrator You are just seeing. Realizing is more important. This was my favorited question, hence I rectified it. And other way moderator himself had approved this edit. He would have judged whether it's correct or not. And by the way does it harm anyone if the question appears on the main page (any kind of server fault or other inconvenience), definitely not. This was a reasonable edit.

Comment: @Integrator All right. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Let us consider the case of $\cos(x)=0.248$ (for which the "exact" solution is $x=1.32018$).

The closest "classical" angle is $x=\frac {\pi}{3}$ and we shall develop $\cos(x)$ as a truncated Taylor series built at $x=\frac {\pi}{3}$. This gives $$\cos(x)=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{3} \left(x-\frac{\pi
   }{3}\right)+O\left(\left(x-\frac{\pi }{3}\right)^2\right)$$ So, we need to find $x$ such that we get the desired cosine value. This gives $x=1.33818$ for which the value of the cosine is $0.230522$.

This being probably not sufficiently good, let us use an higher order expansion built around the same point; this now gives $$\cos(x)=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{3} \left(x-\frac{\pi
   }{3}\right)-\frac{1}{4} \left(x-\frac{\pi }{3}\right)^2+O\left(\left(x-\frac{\pi }{3}\right)^3\right)$$ Solving the quadratic now gives $x=1.31715$ for which the value of the cosine is $0.250939$ which much closer to the desired value.

It is sure that all of the above would have been much better knowing that the closest angle is $\frac{5 \pi}{12}$. Using the same procedure, we would have $$\cos(x)=\frac{1}{4} \left(\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}\right)+\frac{1}{4}
   \left(-\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{6}\right) \left(x-\frac{5 \pi
   }{12}\right)+O\left(\left(x-\frac{5 \pi }{12}\right)^2\right)$$ which would give $x=1.32020$  for which the value of the cosine is $0.247984$.

To summarize, find among the angle $x_0$ for which you know the value of the cosine and polish the solution using a Taylor expansion around this point and solve $$\cos(x)=\cos (x_0)-(x-x_0) \sin (x_0)-\frac{1}{2} (x-x_0)^2 \cos (x_0)+O\left((x-x_0)^3\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

Say we've got $\cos(\theta)=x$.

Then $\theta=\textrm{arcos}(x)=\underbrace{\frac{\pi}{2}-x-\frac{x^3}{6}-\frac{3x^5}{40}+...}_{\textrm{Taylor expansion of arcos(x)}}$.

This is how a calculator would numerically evaluate $\theta$ (to an arbitrary number of terms, probably using the approximation $\pi \approx3.14159$).

Comment: I thought calculators used Cordic

Answer (score 2):

$$
1 - \theta^2/2\approx 1.0471\,,\quad \theta
\approx \pm 2\,\sqrt{\,0.0942\,}\,\ {\rm i}
$$

Answer (score 0):

For real angles, cosine is limited to $1$ in absolute value. Is $1.047$ intended as a placeholder? You can start with an angle you know that is close, then correct

Comment: The OP seems to have reformulated his/her question in the comments.